# Svelte dynamic component assignment updates

Tags: svelte

In Svelte, I am using the value of a store to change the active component on a page, which is working as I would expect.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { eventData } from "./store";
    import A from "./components/A.svelte";
    import B from "./components/B.svelte";

    let element = A;

    eventData.subscribe(({ showB }) => {
        if (showB) {
            element = B;
        } else {
            element = A;
        }
    });
</script>

<div>
    <svelte:component this={element} />
</div>
```

My question is if doing this creates one instance each of A and B which gets swapped in and out as needed, or if it creates a new instance on every change. For example, if I make an HTTP request to load some data in element B, does it run that every time I switch or does it run it once and keep the instance of B stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The svelte documetation says

> The svelte:component element renders a component dynamically, using the component constructor specified as the this property. When the property changes, the component is destroyed and recreated.

https://svelte.dev/docs/special-elements#svelte-component

So you will get new instances

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted will create a new instance of A and B every time you switch, the respective state of these components will also be lost (unless you keep their state in an external store).

If you do not want to create a new instance and keep the internal state you can wrap both components in a `div` element and toggle the **visibility** of that element with css

```html
<script>
<script lang="ts">
  import { eventData } from "./store";
  import A from "./components/A.svelte";
  import B from "./components/B.svelte";
  
  
    let element = A;

    eventData.subscribe(({ showB }) => {
        if (showB) {
            element = B;
        } else {
            element = A;
        }
    });
</script>

<div class:hide={$eventData.showB}>
  <A />
</div>
<div class:hide={!$eventData.showB}>
  <B />
</div>
<style>
  div {
    display: contents;
  }
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

(the `display: contents` above makes it that when the component is visible it will act as if the div was not there)